# How to capture the markdown from a WMD-Editor server side in a ASP.NET website?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wmd

I'm using an `asp:TextBox` as the `wmd-input`. As the user clicks the submit button I wan't to capture the markdown at server side as the `Text` property of my `asp:TextBox` control.

However, instead of the expected markdown, my TextBox at server-side contains the HTML formatted version of the markdown:

`<h1>testing</h1>`

**How do I get the pure markdown?**

PS: At client side I see markdown on the `asp:TextBox`. It's not clear for me when it's getting converted to HTML before post-back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

WMD-Editor supports a configuration that determines the output of the editor. Check out the file optionsExample.html that comes with the downloadable version.

In my case I just needed to add this before the showdown.js reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window['wmd_options'] = {
            output: "Markdown",
            buttons: "bold italic | link blockquote image | ol ul heading hr"
        };
    </script>
```